# Depurar Servicio windows

Tags: c#

tengo una consulta , estoy tratando de depurar un servicio pero me sale este alerta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo que ya tienes varias preguntas, pero ninguna con respuestas aceptadas. Te invito a que sigas el [tour] para ver como funciona este sitio.

Comment: ¿Sabes [qué hacer cuando alguien te responde](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?